# Change android ripple color dynamically

Tags: android, themes, android-button, material-components-android

Is there a way to change the ripple colour of a control programmatically? Specifically, i want to be able to fetch the theme colours from an API and apply them to the whole application. From several answers around, i have learned that android doesn't allow to change the theme dynamically, so I set to implement my own theming.
One thing remains to be changed, the ripple colour:

[image: ripple colour]

- Is there a way to change this dynamically (programatically) for
  a single control?

  - EDIT: Specifically, I want to apply this to `MenuItem`s inside a `NavigationView` and children clickable `RelativeLayout`s views of a `ListView`.
- Is there a reasonable way to do it for the whole application? Like a rough equivalent of changing `colorControlHighlight` ?

Answer (score 1):

With a `MaterialButton` you can use:

```
    button.setRippleColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.selector));
```

Comment: Is this, or something like it, applicable to MenuItems or ListViews?

Comment: @chubakueno The question is if you can use the MaterialButton in a ListView? Or if you can use the same method on other views?

Comment: If there is a similar method for MenuItems inside a NavigationView, or ListView children views. Didn't think this woul be so case-specific, will edit the question to reflect so.

Comment: @chubakueno In a ListView it depends by the view in the items. In the NavigationView is different. You can't use this method.